# Flutter Firestore How to load array from firestore to a list

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, casting

I want to load the array from Firestore into a list in Flutter. I tried to use List.castFrom to convert Firestore array into List, but it does not work.

```
DocumentReference userDocRef = Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(id);
DocumentSnapshot userDocSnapshot = await userDocRef.get();

List groups = await List.castFrom(userDocSnapshot.data['groups']);
```

it shows an error: **Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List'**

This is the array in my Firestore: [image]

What should I do?

Comment: did you try `List groups = userDocSnapshot.data['groups'];`

Comment: Yes, same error

Comment: can you delete this line `List groups = await List.castFrom(userDocSnapshot.data['groups']);
` and check what return from the server; `print(userDocSnapshot.data['groups']);`

Comment: It prints: [], [], {}, [udnhTjnaS2WCUYa5MPnJ], [], []

Comment: the problem is the third one, it's not an array it as map

Comment: What do you mean? Firestore return array as a map?

Comment: No, I mean there is no array in the third document. It is a map not an array. you can check if which one is it; `print("id: ${userDocSnapshot.documentID]} groups: ${userDocSnapshot.data['groups']}")`;

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly turn a Map into a List. You would have to get to use forEach to split the map's key and values. Here is how you can get the Map's values and turn it into a List:

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance
    .reference()
    .child("users/$id")
    .once()
    .then((snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.value != null) {
    snapshot.value.forEach((k, v) {
      myList.add(v);
    });
  } else {
    print("value is null");
  }
});
```